# How to take selected dropdown value in Angular 8 for ngSubmit()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my project I am using Angular 8.
Created method to bind user to project according to their id, tested with postman back end functionality works properly.

My service for bindUser method:

```
 bindUserToProject(userId: number, projectId: number) {
    const seperator = "/";
    const body = { userId, seperator, projectId };
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/bind/', body)
  }
```

Component:

```
export class AddProjectForUserComponent implements OnInit {
  users: any = {};
  projects: any = {};

  constructor(private router: Router, private projectService: ProjectService, private vmService: 
   VmService, private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users = this.getUsersForProject()
    this.projects = this.getProjects()
  }

  getUsersForProject() {
    this.projectService.getUsersForProject().subscribe(u => this.users = u);
  }

  getProjects() {
    this.vmService.getProjectsForVm().subscribe(p => this.projects = p)
  }

  goBackToUserProjects() {
    this.router.navigate(["/user-projects"])
  }

  bindUserToProject(userId: number, projectId: number) {
    this.userService.bindUserToProject(userId, projectId);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bindProject">
    <form #bindProject="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="bindUserToProject()">
      <h2 class="text-center text-primary">Bind User to Projects</h2>   

      <div class="input-group mt-1">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-dot-circle text-info"></i>&nbsp;Users
          </div>
        </div>
       <select name="userId" [(ngModel)]="users.userId" class="form-control" required>
         <option disabled>-Please choose User-</option>
         <option *ngFor="let item of users" [ngValue]="item.userId">
          {{ item.userName }}
         </option>
       </select>
      </div>

      <div class="input-group mt-1">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-dot-circle text-info"></i>&nbsp;Projects
          </div>
        </div>
       <select name="projectId" [(ngModel)]="projects.projectId" class="form-control" required>
         <option disabled>-Please choose Projects-</option>
         <option *ngFor="let item of projects" [ngValue]="item.projectId">
          {{ item.projectName }}
         </option>
       </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group mt-1">
        <button [disabled]="!bindProject.valid" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mr-5" type="submit"><i 
      class="fas fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add</button>
        <button (click)="goBackToUserProjects()" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success"><i 
      class="fas fa-tasks"></i>&nbsp;Go back to user projects</button>  
      </div>

    </form>

  </div>
```

Question is how can I get selected id from both dropdown and pass it to my bindToProject() method.

Comment: Can u change `<form #bindProject="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="bindUserToProject()">` 
To `<form #bindProject="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="console.log(bindProject)">` and post the results to this comment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the select values with some variables say `selectedProject` and `selectedUser`.

**app.component.ts :**

```
selectedUser : number;
selectedProject : number;

bindUserToProject() {
    this.userService.bindUserToProject(this.selectedUser, this.selectedProject);
}
```

**app.component.html :**

```
<select name="userId" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser">
    <option disabled>-Please choose User-</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of users" [ngValue]="item.userId">
        {{ item.userName }}
    </option>
</select>

<select name="projectId" [(ngModel)]="selectedProject">
    <option disabled>-Please choose Projects-</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of projects" [ngValue]="item.projectId">
        {{ item.projectName }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3udq1g

Comment: hi  ,you have to use `this`  her `this.userService.bindUserToProject(this.selectedUser, this.selectedProject);`

Comment: I already check your answer ant it 's working , even I will clone your demo 

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable in your component called something like `selectedUserId`, change `[(ngModel)]="users.userId"` to  `[(ngModel)]="selectedUserId"`. Then in `bindUserToProject()` you can access that value directly from the component.

You can do the same for the projects dropdown.

Comment: why do you think this `[(ngModel)]="users.userId"` not working 

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmavi because users in this case is an array. You'd have to select one user from the array for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```html
<form #bindProject="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="bindUserToProject(bindProject.value)">

  <select name="userId"  class="form-control" ngModel required>
    <option disabled>-Please choose User-</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of users" [ngValue]="item.userId">
    {{ item.userName }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <select name="projectId"  class="form-control" ngModel required>
    <option disabled>-Please choose Projects-</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of projects" [ngValue]="item.projectId">
    {{ item.projectName }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <button  type="submit">
    Add
  </button>

</form>
```

component

```
  bindUserToProject({userId, projectId}) {
    this.userService.bindUserToProject(userId, projectId);
  }
```

`bindUserToProject` will get the hole form value but this `{userId, projectId}` is ES2015 feature called destruction

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aaagyc)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has same issue my service also was wrong which threw exception json Parser.
I changed this one to and it worked fine:

```
 bindUserToProject(userId: number, projectId: number) {  
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/bind/' + userId + "/" + projectId, {})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the following step of solution-:

1. Initialize two variable for userId and projectId.
2. Apply these variable in ngModel like `[(ngModel)]="UserId"` and `[(ngModel)]="projectId"`
3. use `(ngSubmit)="bindUserToProject()"`
4. In component file use initialized variables in `bindUserToProject()` function.
5. Select dropdown and click Submit.
6. Now, you have a selected value in your variable.